# Absolute paths in Ant property file

Tags: ant, properties

I have a property file containing absolute paths to jars etc. When using these properties they are prefixed with the basedir specified in the build file. **How do I get the absolute path?**

build.properties:

```
mylib=/lib/mylib.jar
```

build.xml:

```
<project name="myproject" basedir=".">
  <property file="build.properties"/>
  ...${mylib}...
</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look at the property task :

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html

By using the location attribute e.g. :

```
<property name="my.abs.path" location="my.relative.path"/>
<echo message="My abs.path is : ${my.abs.path}"/>
```

This will expand any relative properties to their full absolute path. Of course the path is expanded relatively to the project's basedir.

Comment: I would like to have the absolute paths in a file though. Is that possible?

Comment: @AndersOlofsson I am a little confused. You want to save the absolute paths of some properties into a file?

Comment: @Anders: read http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html. If the location attribute value start with a /, it's left unchanged. Else, the basedir is prepended.

Comment: The thing is that I want the paths in a property FILE. When I use properties in the property file they are prefixed/prepended with the basedir.

Comment: @Anders : It's not the property task that is appending the basedir. It's some other task, which you haven't shown in your question, and which uses the property. If you just execute <echo message="${mylib}"/>, you'll see that the property value is displayed as is, without the basedir prepended.